# Rails render index (JSON) after update returning empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

In my small Rails app, I want to update an object through json format, and on success receive the index.json.jbuilder content (using the `render :index` on JSON format in update). But for some reason, I just get an empty array... I tried many options without success, so any help would be welcome! Thx in advance

**My routes**

```
resources :coaches, only: [:show] do
  resource :calendar, only: :show, defaults: { format: :json }
  resources :events, only: [:index, :update], defaults: { format: :json }
end
```

**My controller**

```
respond_to :json, only: :index

def index
  @events = Event.all
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @event.update(event_params)
      if params[:commit] == I18n.t('next')
        format.html { redirect_to booking_event_confirm_path(@event) }
      elsif params[:commit] == I18n.t('confirm')
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Event was successfully confirmed." }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to booking_event_path(@event), notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :index, status: :ok }
      end
    else
      if params[:commit] == I18n.t('next')
        format.html { render :training }
      elsif params[:commit] == I18n.t('confirm')
        format.html {
          # TODO: why is the url not persistent? ('/confirm' being removed even if page display seems ok)
          render :confirm
        }
      else
        format.html { render :training }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What's inside `index.json.jbuilder`? I suppose you need to define `@events` in udate action to solve the issue

Comment: @Vasilisa If I'm right `@events` is already defined in the `def index`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is defined, but you are in create action

Comment: Omg you were right! I added to my update method (action), a `@events = Event.all`just before the format.json line, and it worked! But isnt'it a bit ugly to do that? Maybe there is a cleaner method (param to render method...)? Anyway, thx for helping !

Comment: It's common way for such things, when you render different template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `@events` in update action to render it as json

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @event.update(event_params)
      if ... 
       ....
      else
        @events = Event.all
        format.json { render :index, status: :ok }
      end
    else
      ....
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You were right, thank you! Btw, do you think there is a better way to define that variable?
I thought the `render :index` would automatically call the @events defined in there.. Anyway, thx again for your help!